# VS Code git.path error

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

So I am having a problem where when I launch VS, it gives me the following error:

Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Looking for git in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Looking for git in: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe

Git installation not found.

I have Git installed, but not on my C: drive. I tried using the git.path command in the settings menu, but it won't work.

My settings are as listed:

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "git.path": G:\Git\Git\bin
}
```

The bin file is where the git.exe executable is, and I have tried just using the  G:\Git\Git path. (I had a double folder because the installer created a new one)
I am not completely sure of what the problem is, but it would really help to have an answer.

Comment: Try adding that path to your environment variable PATH

Comment: Ok will try thanks.